# Using vue-styled-components in Single file component approach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, styled-components

Here's my styled component file named styles.js

```
import styled from 'vue-styled-components';

export const StyledTitle = styled.h1`
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: palevioletred;
`;

export const Wrapper = styled.section`
    padding: 4em;
    background: papayawhip;
`;
```

Then in my .vue single file component

```
<template>
  <div class="m-15">
    <StyledTitle>SUBMIT YOUR DETAILS</StyledTitle>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { StyledTitle, Wrapper } from "./styles.js";

export default {
  name: "BuyNowCustomerDetails",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>
```

Not working!

**Error**

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register the external components inside your export statement:

```
import { StyledTitle, Wrapper } from "./styles.js";

export default {
  name: "BuyNowCustomerDetails",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  //register components
  components: {
     StyledTitle
  }
};
```